# Event processing both parallel and sequential

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns

I am designing a java module to process events sent by other external systems.
All events received by systems will go through a mapping and then queued into a ThreadPoolExecutor for further processing.

Fairly simple.

Now the catch here is if I receive an event with the same key say "SystemID + EventEntityID", I must process them in order.
As event frequency is moderate to high, I can't process all of them sequentially. Thats out of question.

So somehow, when I receive an event I need to make sure any event with the same key is not either in processing or in queue before I push it in queue.
Also if I find it under processing or in queue, I have to keep it somewhere and later push to the queue when existing one finished processing.

I am not sure what is the good design approach for this solution. Any help would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the flow of an event is: received -> mapped to queue -> executed.
Now there can be many solutions, with different effects. Because I don't actually know your system, what I present may not be the best fit, and is just a basic direction for implementation.

To achieve what you need, all we actually need to modify is the queue. So we will create an implementation of a queue which will support this.

Usually when I encounter problems with a key which can match multiple values, I use a `Map<K, Collection<V>>` Where `K` is the key type and `V` is the value type. Of course this is not a queue, but it will be used as part of our implementation of the queue.

When a new event is added we can place it into the collection in the map matching the key. From there it can be queued.

Priority queuing is needed, so we will use a sort of `PriorityQueue` (implementation may change).

We need to take care of several things:

- Receive new event into map. Which is rather simple, can be done by putting into the collection value of the map.
- Transfer from map to queue. We need to take from the first value in the collection from each key into the priority queue. However this can only be done once the last value has being processed.
- Poll from queue to user. Simply retrieve the first value from the priority queue.

#### Receive new event into map

This is done in our push method, which will receive an event, and is pretty simple:

```
Collection<V> collection = map.get(key);
if (collection == null) {
    collection = (create collection)
    map.put(key, collection);
}
collection.add(value);
```

#### Transfer from map to queue

This is the most problematic, since we need to find a way to know whether or not an event of each type is in the queue and when the last event was processed.
The first idea I have is to use a proxy event value. This value will contain that data, and will look something like that:

```
interface StoredEventType {
    // when a new event of this type was received
    void registerNewEvent(Event e);
    // move from map to queue
    void pollNextEventInto(Queue<StoredEvent> q);
}
interface StoredEvent {
    // when the execution was done for this event, this will be called.
    boolean isDone();
    // the execution should call this to update that it is done.
    void onDone();
}
```

What will happen is that only when `isDone` is called, will a new event placed in the queue when `pollNextEventInto` is called. For this to work, the execution task must call `onDone` at the end.

When is `pollNextEventInto` called? Likely it should be called when our queue implementation is polled. This is the only thing guaranteed to keep happening while the executor runs.

#### Poll from queue to user

This is also pretty simple. First perform `pollNextEventInto` on all the stored keys, to make sure the priority queue is updated. And then simply poll from the priority queue.

#### Implementation Summary

This is not a perfect idea. Concurrency must be ensured for it, and abstraction is not the best. But it those give a direction on how. Also note how most of the work is done in `poll`. This is because `poll` is used internally for the execution, while `push` is more external, interfacing in some way with other systems.

If you want to go more into brainstorming about this, I would love to.

### Edit

I've had the opportunity to sit down and check this implementation. It works well. Not the most clean code... Though with some effort it can be.

The event queue implementation should probably support blocking `poll` for thread which polls from it and executes.

When running, I've relied on `Future` to check on the event processing finished. It's quite useful for async work.

Comment: I liked this idea. To put it simply, independent of how we implement. 
-try to acquire a lock on a particular eventtype on event receive. 
-If lock is acquired, event is pushed to the processing queue. 
-If lock is not acquired, event is queued in a holding queue. 
-processing thread releases the lock on eventtype. 
-holding queue is polled to check if lock can be acquired and event is pushed to processing queue. 
I hope my understanding is correct.  
The other aspects which I have to think now is memory usage to store all events and how to write effective polling of holding queue

Comment: Something of the like. The danger part is that you *have* to make sure that the lock is  released when processing is done, which is why I preferred using a `Future` object. Polling shouldn't be to hard, using some `Condition` and `Lock` for example. And memory usage really depends on the amount of events and the data they contain.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a set of Actors, organized in a map, each actor accessed by a key. Actors with different keys work in parallel. Each actor with given key handles events sequentially.

```
Map<Key,Actor> actors = new ActorMap();

void receiveEvent(Event e) {
   Actor actor = actors.get(e.key);
   actor.onNext(e);
}


class ActorMap extends ConcurrentHashMap<Key,Actor> {
   public Actor get(K key) {
       return computeIfAbsent(key, (key)->new Actor(key));
   }
}
```

As an actor library, you can use Akka, my [DF4J](https://github.com/akaigoro/df4j), or even https://github.com/akaigoro/CodeSamples/blob/master/src/main/java/actor/simpleactor/SimpleActor.java

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I see using Actors we can process same key events sequentially.
But my requirement is not just sequential but also in order.

Comment: Actors has input queues for messages. Usually that queues keep the order of messages and actors handle the messages in the same order as they are posted to the queues.